# How expensive is to run full node on Solana?

Tags: rpc, mainnet, node

In Bitcoin, there are two parties - miners and node runners. While, the miners are running PoW operations, the node runners are only concerned with maintaining the record of the full ledger. Is there a similar distinction on Solana as well or maintaining full node costs resources similar to running validator mentioned on this page: [Validator Requirements](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs)?

Answer (score 3):

To run a voting validator (or a full node) on the Solana network, it requires around 3 SOL per epoch.

To run a RPC only validator, it requires no SOL.

Outside of that, there are server costs that depend on where and who you host with. I won't put any providers in here in favor of the Solana team not wanting advertisements in answers, but you can expect anywhere from $600 to upwards of $2k monthly in hosting costs.

If you are looking to calculate profitability, here is a decent tool. https://cogentcrypto.io/ValidatorProfitCalculator

Comment: Just to add, Solana has a list of providers here https://solana.com/rpc